# How can I change the azure directory when I am using the login.windows.net page

Tags: azure-active-directory, azureportal

This [url](https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token&client_id=%7Bclient-id%7D&redirect_uri=%7Bredirect-uri%7D&response_mode=form_post&nonce=a4014117-28aa-47ec-abfb-f377be1d3cf5%20&resource=https://noammeetings.resources.lync.com&prompt=admin_consent) uses one of the azure active directory I can access. Unfortunately, it's not the good one. How can I change this behavior to point it to the good one or to give me the choice after login ? Changing the directory in the Azure Portal Subscription Filter doesn't work.

I would prefer a solution that works without changing the url (I will have to use Skype for Business Online Application Registration Portal and I have the same problem with it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to use the OAuth2 authorization endpoint specific to your tenant. In order to get the authorization token specific to tenant you need to simply write :

```
https://login.windows.net/{yourtenantname}.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authorize?api-version=1.0
```

or

```
https://login.windows.net/{tenantid}/oauth2/authorize?api-version=1.0
```

Please refer to this [blog](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/08/26/the-common-endpoint-walks-like-a-tenant-talks-like-a-tenant-but-is-not-a-tenant/) for additional details.